# Streaming of a resource with proper acquisition and release

Tags: haskell, streaming

This is a question about the Haskell [`streaming`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) library.

`Stream (Of a) m r` is a "stream of individual Haskell values derived from actions in some monad `m` and returning a value of type `r`". `Streaming.Prelude` defines many useful functions that allow nice streaming applications:

```
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
S.print $ do
    S.yield "a"
    S.yield "b"
    S.yield "c"
```

The [tutorial](https://github.com/michaelt/streaming-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md) is good for getting started.

Now, the particular issue at hand is how to use this framework with a monad that requires careful instantiation and release of resources. The [`streaming-with`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-with) package seems to be the right candidate, it has a function

```
bracket :: MonadMask m => m a -> (a -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

that acquires (`m a`), releases (`a->m c`) and uses (`a->m b`) a resource. All three actions are encapsulated in the returned `m b`. `withFile` is a good example for how to use this:

```
withFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> m r) -> m r
withFile fp md = bracket (liftIO (openFile fp md)) (liftIO . hClose)
```

Acquisition and release of the handle are nicely sandwiching the usage `Handle->m r`.

But: I absolutely do not see how this should be used with `Stream (Of a) m r`. I have to provide an `a->m b` and I get a `m b`. How is this supposed to be connected so that I obtain a `Stream`?

To figure this out, let's play with `withFile`:

```
import System.IO 

use :: Handle -> IO (S.Stream (Of String) IO ())
use = return . S.repeatM . hGetLine

main :: IO ()
main = do
    str <- S.withFile "input.dat" ReadMode use
    S.print str
```

but that results in `hGetLine: illegal operation (handle is closed)`. That actually makes sense, by the time `S.print str` is called `withFile` has already acquired and released the handle.
So let's move the stream consumption inside the `use` function:

```
use :: Handle -> IO ()
use h = do
    S.print $ S.repeatM (hGetLine h)
```

and that gives a `hGetLine: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)`. I'm not quite sure what this error means. An `isEOFError` would be acceptable, but 'invalid byte sequence'? In any case, this doesn't work either.

I'm running out of ideas... How is this done?

The `withFile` is just a toy example, the question is really about how to correctly create and consume a stream inside a `bracket`.

Answer (score 0):

> let's move the stream consumption inside the use function

This is indeed the right approach.

I'm actually getting a proper `hGetLine: end of file` when running the example code. The problem is that `S.repeatM (hGetLine h)` never bothers to check if it has reached then end of the file, and throws an exception when it bumps into it.

The following definition of `use` doesn't have that problem:

```
use :: Handle -> IO ()
use h = do
    S.print $ S.untilRight $ do eof <- System.IO.hIsEOF h
                                if eof then Right <$> pure ()
                                       else Left <$> hGetLine h
```

It uses the [`untilRight`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:untilRight) function.